# Unable to reference SQLite.interop.dll

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

Okay, I know this has been asked a few time on here but none of the advice helps.  I downloaded SQLite, went into the bin and got the DLLs from there.  I'm trying to publish a SQLite interface and when I compile and run this is what I get
[image]

I've tried adding the .DLL through the nuget manager in VS 2015 and manually.  Both ways through the following error message.

[image]

I'm at my wits end.  I don't know what to do.
Here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string db = @"URI = file:C:\Users\Mason\Documents\test.db";

            try
            {
                var con = new SQLiteConnection(db);
                con.Open();
                var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from test";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.Read();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.Read();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add `SQLite.Interop.dll` as a reference.

The good news is... you don't need to.

It just needs to be available for the managed SQLite assemblies to use.

So do this instead...

Copy the correct `SQLite.Interop.dll` build (x86,x64) to your project folder, and *include* it in your project as you would with any file (image, icon, etc.).

Then, in its `Properties` set:

`Build Action` to `Content` 
 `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`

Rebuild and Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks that did it.